# restricted write18 is preventing the command: runsystem(gnuplot filename.gnuplot) from being executed

Tags: texmaker, mactex, gnuplot, shell-escape

That pretty much says it all.  I'm on a mac, using Texmaker, `gnuplot` works well with `aquaterm`, I can pass code for diagrams from GeoGebra (geometry package) that works fine.

It seems like using `gnuplot` is the issue.

I get the following in my log file:

```
runsystem(gnuplot kjhgf.func0.gnuplot)...disabled (restricted).
Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `kjhgf.func0.table' not found. on input 
line 22.
```

I am wondering how to "unrestrict" `gnuplot` (I assume `runsystem` is not the offender) or fully enable `\write18`.

I've tried `-shell-escape` (and `-enable-write18`) and many of its variants, although I have a lot of options in Texmaker's preferences.

Comment: You have to enable `--shell-escape` while compiling and have `gnuplot` installed in your system.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. i've got gnuplot installed (i can call it from the terminal and create graphics in aquaterm).  i may not be enabling --shell-escape properly, but i have tried to in numerous ways.

Comment: Can you try running LaTeX from the Terminal with `pdflatex -shell-escape`, instead of running it from Texmaker?

Comment: omg! sure.  i tried it and it seems to do the job ...

Comment: ... although i am now staring at ** as a prompt with a couple dozen lines of code to deal with.

Comment: *** newbie alert *** :|

Comment: You can also write a `user` command in texmaker with `--shell-escape` so that you simply click.

Comment: good grief! well, now i have the output that i sought, problem is i did three (count 'em three) things: 1) i moved -shell-escape to the beginning of the call for pdflatex (rather than at the end 2) i closed tekmaker and reopened it and 3) i ran pdflatex -shell-escape in the terminal.  thanks for the help. i'll try, one-by-one,  to figure out what the problem was and will post it here for the interested, the eager, and the doomed.  cheers.

Comment: The right way to handle this is not to run with `--shell-escape` but to add `gnuplot` to the list of programmes which may be executed when *restricted* shell-escape is enabled (which it is by default). I cannot currently find clear instructions for doing this, however. The list of such programmes is in the default `texmf.cnf` but you shouldn't edit that. Is there a suitable place to configure this for the local installation?